# Can sscanf in C write on char* instead of char[]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, scanf

I'm looking for the simplest way in standard C to parse a string. The number of words inside the string is fixed, but the length of each single word is not. The code will be running on a microprocessor with limited memory so I can't just allocate an overkill buffer, I'd like to allocate just the memory that I need.

The following code works, but I'd like the single words to be char* . Is there some way around this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

  char * my_words = "foo bar 1 2";

  char word1[20];
  char word2[20];
  char word3[20];
  char word4[20];

  int match = sscanf(my_words,"%s %s %s %s",word1,word2,word3,word4);

  printf("Matches: %d\r\n",match);

  printf("%s\r\n",word1);
  printf("%s\r\n",word2);
  printf("%s\r\n",word3);
  printf("%s\r\n",word4);

  return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You should look up what's an array and what's a pointer. Also search for "C array decays to pointer". Then ask yourself what you really want to do here.

Comment: Since you're running in an constrained environment: can you use `malloc`? Are you allowed to use variable length arrays?

Comment: And finally think about whether you need the source string afterwards or if its memory may be reused!

Comment: Using the `scanf` and `printf` family on a restricted MCU is probably already a bad idea.

Comment: well, you could replace `char word1[20];` with `char *word1 = malloc(20);` but that just makes your code more verbose.

Comment: If `my_words` were actually a char array instead of a string literal, you could change the spaces into terminators and then use a bunch of pointers

Answer (score 1):

For parsing you can use [strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) function. A simple approach can be like that also you can modify it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    char const *my_words = "foo bar 1 2";
    char *str = malloc(1 + strlen(my_words));
    strcpy(str, my_words);
    int countWord = 0;
    char * pch;
    printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
    pch = strtok (str," ");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        ++countWord;
    }

    printf("Total words = %d\n", countWord);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(strlen(my_words));` --> `malloc(strlen(my_words)+1);` for the `nul` terminator.

Comment: @snr: Or `char my_words[] = "foo bar 1 2"` and then no copy is needed.

Comment: @BillLynch of course but I want the op to show a simple usage of `malloc` because he mentioned

Comment: Also, you are inconsistent with the string separaters for `strtok`. Is it `" "` or is it `" ,.-"`?

Comment: `strtok` may not quite fit the OP need, since `strtok` modifies the string it's given.

Comment: @bishop simple approach. if you have better idea you can share with us :)

Comment: Until he has to debug a SIGSEGV. :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how simple and standard your code should be.

If your target supports POSIX 2008 (recent GNU libc does), then you could use `m` modifier as [docs suggest](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to allocate just enough space to read data.

But if you have to stay with ANSI C, then probably you're stuck to functions like `strtok`/`strtok_r` or alike.

Answer (score 0):

And in the event you must roll your own, the algorithm goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    /* your input, I'll presume its constant */
    const char *input = " foo  bar 1    2 ";

    /* here is your array of char*.
     * you indicate the number of words is fixed */
    char *words[4];

    /* the algo */
    size_t b = 0;
    size_t e = 0;
    size_t l = strlen(input);
    int w = 0;
    while (b < l) {
        b += strspn(input + b, " ");
        e  = b + strcspn(input + b, " ");
        words[w] = malloc(e - b + 1);
        strncpy(words[w], input + b, e - b);
        w++;
        b = e+1;
    }

    /* debugging, outputs in reverse order */
    while (w--) {
        printf("%s\n", words[w]);
        free(words[w]);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Obviously, you'd want to add error checking.